# Drawing specific circles with Qt

Tags: qt, qpainter

I need to draw many circles in sequence. When I draw next circle, the intersection with others should be hidden. Please give me an example code.

[On this picture firstly I draw "1" circle, then "2" circle, then "3" circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54kMN.png)

Comment: Fill each circle with white colour.

Comment: @CroCo but next circle's border will be drawn over previous circle, isn't it?

Comment: If it non transparent just draw circle 3, 2, and 1 in sequence with fill white for all circle

Comment: use `QPainter::drawEllipse(...)` with white brush and any color pen you want. and paint the circles in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QPainter` to do this work.

```
# Create a place to draw the circles.
circles = QImage( 700, 700, QImage.Format_ARGB32 )

# Init the painter
p = QPainter( circles )

# DestinationOver results in the current painting 
# going below the existing image.
p.setCompositionMode( QPainter.CompositionMode_DestinationOver )
p.setRenderHints( QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing )

p.setBrush( Qt.white )
p.setPen( QPen( Qt.green, 3.0 ) )

# Paint the images in the PROPER order: 1, 2, 3, etc
p.drawEllipse( QPoint( 300, 300 ), 200, 200 )
p.drawEllipse( QPoint( 450, 450 ), 100, 100 )
p.drawEllipse( QPoint( 300, 450 ), 150, 150 )

p.end()

# The above image is transparent. If you prefer to have
# a while/color bg do this:
final = QImage( 700 ,700, QImage.Format_ARGB32 )
final.fill( Qt.lightgray )

p = QPainter( final )

# Now we want the current painting to be above the existing
p.setCompositionMode( QPainter.CompositionMode_SourceOver )
p.setRenderHints( QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing )

p.drawImage( QRect( 0, 0, 700, 700 ), circles )

p.end()

# Save the file.
final.save( "/tmp/trial.png" )
```

Note that the same code can we used for painting a widget directly. In case of widget, override its `::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* )` and do this work.

Comment: This doesn't work, `error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'QImage' to 'QPainter'`